# How can I change local variable inside my fuction

Tags: python

I'm doing an easy program in python where I have my turtle and can go around and it draws but I want to make it so that when I press shift the `.pensize(x)` goes up by one and when I press control it goes down by one but I don't know how to do it.

Code:

```
def pensizeUp():
    x = 0
    x += 1
    k.pensize(x)
def pensizeDown():
    x = 0
    x -= 1
    k.pensize(x) 

wn.onkeypress(pensizeUp, "Shift_L")
wn.onkeypress(pensizeDown, "Control_l")
```

I tried searching it up but I couldn't find out how to do it. I also tried different things but in the end I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: Try addinf global keyword to local variable x. That is global x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pen size is maintained as an internal variable of the object. The `turtle` module implements an older style of getter and setter that you can use, instead of maintaining a separate, external variable. Here is a basic example (you may have to adapt it).

```py
import turtle


def bigger():
    t = turtle.getturtle()
    t.pensize(t.pensize() + 1)

def smaller():
    t = turtle.getturtle()
    t.pensize(t.pensize() - 1)


def setup():
    turtle.getscreen().onkeypress(bigger, "Shift_L")
    turtle.getscreen().onkeypress(smaller, "Control_L")
    turtle.listen()

setup()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

So your first problem is that you are doing `x = 0` every time you call the functions and your `x` is not global

```
x = 0
def pensizeUp():
    global x
    x += 1
    k.pensize(x)
def pensizeDown():
    global x
    x -= 1
    k.pensize(x)

wn.onkeypress(pensizeUp, "Shift_L")
wn.onkeypress(pensizeDown, "Control_l")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `x` variable outside the functions
and add a `global x` inside each:

```
x = 0
def pensizeUp():
    global x
    x += 1
    k.pensize(x)
def pensizeDown():
    global x
    x -= 1
    k.pensize(x) 

wn.onkeypress(pensizeUp, "Shift_L")
wn.onkeypress(pensizeDown, "Control_l")
```

Comment: I already tried that but then its a different variable its a global one at least I think thats the issue

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Could you elaborate on that? That's also what I would have done, and besides the missing `global x` call before the definition of `x = 0`, it's a good solution.

Comment: introducing global variables is almost never the right answer.

Comment: @Mathieu Please rollback your edit.

Comment: I’m saying that the edit was unnecessary for the program to work. (Also, there should be a way of doing this without a global variable, not that I can think of one right now :-(. )

Comment: @quamrana the obvious way would be to return `x`. But then you should use an assignment to call a function that also modifies the state of the program (moves the turtle). This is IMO even worst than globals. But maybe there's a not so obvious way...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `global` variables, than you can create your own class and store x into it:

```
class myGlobal:
    x = 0

def pensizeUp():
    myGlobal.x += 1
    
def pensizeDown():
    myGlobal.x -= 1

myGlobal.x = 100  # Value at begining
print(myGlobal.x)  # Output: 100

pensizeUp()
print(myGlobal.x)  # Output: 101

pensizeDown()
print(myGlobal.x)  # Output: 100
```

**UPD:** I think, when you talk about changing the local variable inside function you want something like this:

```
# THIS PART OF THE CODE SHOULDN'T WORK
def pensizeUp():
    x += 1
    k.pensize(x)

def pensizeDown():
    x -= 1
    k.pensize(x)
```

The problem is that Python can really get values from global scope but can't change them. As solution you can also try this:

```
def pensizeUp():
    xx = x + 1
    k.pensize(xx)
    return xx

def pensizeDown():
    xx = x - 1
    k.pensize(xx)
    return xx

x = 100  # Value at begining
print(x)  # Output: 100

x = pensizeUp()
print(x)  # Output 101

x = pensizeDown()
print(x)  # Output 100
```

Here, inside functions, Python automatically find and read `x` from your main part of the code. But as you can see, than you need to create additional assignment to save new value and after return it. Though I recommend **avoid** this practice, because on big projects even getting value from outside the function without using `global` scope or classes can be pretty unpredicted.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didnt know I could use this its gonna help me a lot in other programs too. : )

Comment: This is still a global variable by another name.

Comment: I m new to programming and pzthon and I didnt get to classes yet so I didnt knew how to do it.